# How to find the source of audit failure in Windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I get audit failure messages in the security event logs, every second.

```
Event id: 4625
logon type: 3
Process name: lasass.exe
failed login: schOPSSH
```

The COPSSH (SSH for Windows) was installed on the machine and its user was svcOPSSH, not schOPSSH. So, I thought that the person who installed misconfigured it, I stopped the SSH service, even I removed the software and deleted all users except admin, but I still get login attempts with that username. I checked all services and its credentials, everything was okay. I search the registry with the user "schOPSSH", couldn't find any record.

Do you have any idea to find the source of this login attempt? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my case, there was brute force attack from external IP. I didn't expect that. I used the [MS Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/4865) to check incoming requests.